# When Edit (delete) Table Columns in Power Query from SQL database , is this edit permanant?

Tags: excel-2010, powerquery

I am trying to connect to my organisation's SQL database using Power Query to create some reports. I need to delete/edit some tables and join multiple tables to come up with the desired report output...

I don't want the change or edit I will do on the excel-power query to reflect on the live database but just in excel .

Comment: What is your question? You've stated what you're trying to do, but you haven't provided details about what you've tried and where you're getting stuck. How can we help?

Comment: I have connected already to the SQL database and trying to delete some columns which I don't think will be needed in the reporting...that's why I am asking , If I delete will it make a permanent delete on the D.B??? which I don' t want to.

Comment: @Matt U refer comment

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, any button you press in the Power Query Editor interface **does not modify the source database**. I must admit that I have not found any page in the [Microsoft Docs on Power Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/) that states this clearly. The page [*What is Power Query?*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-what-is-power-query) states that:

> Power Query is a data transformation and data preparation engine. Power Query comes with a graphical interface for getting data from sources and a Power Query Editor for applying transformations.

Other pages contain similarly general and vague descriptions but let me reassure you that any data transformation you carry out by using the Power Query Editor interface will not modify your SQL database. All you see in Power Query is a view of the source database.

Seeing as you are connecting to a SQL database, it is likely that [query folding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/query-folding-basics) is activated. This means that when you remove a column (or row), this will update the SQL query used to extract the data from the database. That query is written as a single SELECT statement that can contain multiple clauses like GROUP BY and WHERE. Transformations that add data (e.g. Add Custom Column, Fill Down) are not included in the query, they are carried out only within the Power Query engine. You can read more about this [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-folding).

**How to edit a database with Power Query when native SQL queries are supported**

That being said, you can actually edit a database from within Power Query if the database supports the use of native SQL queries, if you have write permission for the database, and if you edit and run one of the two M functions that let you write native SQL queries. Here is an example using the [Sql.Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/sql-database) function:

```
Sql.Database("servername", "dbname", [Query = "DROP TABLE tablename"])
```

And here is an example using the [Value.NativeQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/value-nativequery) function:

```
Source = Sql.Databases("servername"){[Name="dbname"]}[Data],
#"Native Query" = Value.NativeQuery(Source, "DROP TABLE tablename")
```

Unless you have changed the default Query Options, these functions should raise a warning message requiring you to permit running the query:

[image: query_permission]

This prevents you from modifying the database without confirmation, so any database modification cannot happen just by accident.

---

I verified this using Excel Microsoft 365 (Version 2108) on Windows 10 64-bit connected to a local SQL Server 2019 (15.x) database.

Comment: thanks for the very insightful response. All that I needed to hear

Comment: @rolandkayver Happy to have been of help! I invite you to [mark my answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).